# Converting a 24px, 36px Vector Drawable to Bitmap returns same sized icon

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, android-vectordrawable

ic_business_white_36px, ic_business_white_24px, when converting these vector drawables to bitmap they look the same size, like a 24dp icon, how to convert them efficiently so they have their own sizes? Im using the code below to convert my vector drawable to bitmap and I'm trying to display them in a google map. Thanks!!!

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), drawableId);

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    width = width > 0 ? width : 1;
    int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    height = height > 0 ? height : 1;

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
```

Comment: why do you have two versions on vector drawable that differ only in size? vector drawables are size independent after all...

Comment: @pskink ahh ok got it, so i give the bitmap whatever size I want right

Comment: ok what size do you want? just use `width` and `height` you want, your drawing code is just fine

Comment: @pskink i want the icon to be 36dp, did some research and found this method Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,int,int,false);  what should go in the second and third parameter

Comment: no, no, no, do not scale bitmaps just set width and height to size you want and call "resized" vector drawable   `#draw` method. that way you will have no pixelation on your output bitmap